# How to use Telerik ajax and Panel

Tags: ajax, telerik

I have a problem with AJAX.
AJAX update field that not specified in configuration. Can you tell me why ajax updated "textbox2" after I change the RadComboBox index?
(here is a simplified code of my application)

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="rlpLoadingPanel" runat="server" Skin="Default" />
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>

        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="cmbTest">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="textBox1" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="textBox2" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>


        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="myPanel2">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="myPanel1" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>

    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel1">

    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbTest_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 1" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 2" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 3" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 4" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 5" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 6" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="test 7" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="textBox1"></telerik:RadTextBox>

    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="textBox2"></telerik:RadTextBox>



    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="myPanel2">
        <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="tButton" OnClick="tButton_Click" Text="Button"></telerik:RadButton>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

This is code on server side:

```
protected void cmbTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {            
        textBox1.Text = "textValue1";
        textBox2.Text = "textValue2";
    }
```

When I move:

```
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="tButton">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="myPanel1" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

from my ajax configuration everythis is work normal. I dont understand the link between this and changing the RadComboBox index. Why "myPanel1" have inbluence on this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>

        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="cmbTest">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="textBox1" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="textBox2" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />
        </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>

    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Comment: No, I don't want to change value "textBox2" usign ajax. This is reason why I don't add
<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="textBox2" LoadingPanelID="rlpLoadingPanel" />

"textBox2.Text = "textValue2";" is just a demonstration that telerik ajax "update" value of textBox2 although I have not mentioned in the ajax settings